# Cursor only outputs last value

Tags: android

The log shows all the data but it only outputs the last value in textView, any ideas on why?

```
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {

        //Log to test cursor data
        Log.i("Cursor", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(c));


        do {
            String cow = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cow"));
            String score = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("score"));

            textViewOutputcow.setText(cow + "\n");
            textViewOutputscore.setText(score + "\n");
        } while (c.moveToNext());

    }
    c.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time through the loop you are setting the text content, not adding to it. You could do it using a StringBuffer like so:

```
StringBuffer cowBuffer=new StringBuffer();
StringBuffer scoreBuffer=new StringBuffer();

do {
    String cow = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cow"));
    String score = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("score"));

    cowBuffer.append(cow + "\n");
    scoreBuffer.append(score + "\n");
    }
while (c.moveToNext());


textViewOutputcow.setText(cowBuffer.toString());
textViewOutputscore.setText(scoreBuffer.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks, so obvious to me now

Comment: Use StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you keep updating the content of the textview after every iteration. Effectively, you get to see just the values of the last row in the cursor.